# How to add Contols Dynamically in DataGridView Row in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView with Different Control Type in Each row now i want  to create control in each row according to that Control Type Is it Possible?
if Yes then How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add control on the OnRowDatabound of your grid, then you can a controls to your row

To add a control to a cell use

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(myObject);
    }
}
```

To add a control to the entire row use

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        row.Controls.Add(myObject);
    }
}
```

Have a look here for the windows forms Grid

You can create your own column class by inheriting the DataGridViewColumn class or any of its derived classes to provide custom appearance, behavior, or hosted controls. For more information, see How to: Customize Cells and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control by Extending Their Behavior and Appearance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

How to: Customize Cells and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control by Extending Their Behavior and Appearance
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Followin error occurs :-(                                                 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It is a Windows Form Application and its not a Gridview ,it is a DataGridView of windows application

Comment: Try the value propertie, cause it can hold an object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx