# Window forms - How to add buttons dynamically to datagridview manually?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
// Add columns to datatable
datatable.Columns.Add("No.");
datatable.Columns.Add("First name");
datatable.Columns.Add("Last name");
// Add rows to datatable
foreach (var row in EmployeeContext.Employees)  //EmployeeContext.Employees is a static list
{
    datatable.Rows.Add(row.No, row.FirstName, row.LastName);
}
//Clear datagridview
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Refresh();

//Add 'column name' and 'header texts' to datagridview
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("No", "No.");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FirstName", "First name");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("LastName", "Last name");
//Add 'button' dynamically to datagridview
DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
deleteButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
deleteButton.HeaderText = "Delete";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteButton);

//Define datapropertyname using 'column name' property defined in previous step
dataGridView1.Columns["No"].DataPropertyName = "No.";
dataGridView1.Columns["FirstName"].DataPropertyName = "First name";
dataGridView1.Columns["LastName"].DataPropertyName = "Last name";
dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
```

Problem 1: Can see Buttons at 4th row but index shows as '0' instead of three
Problem 2:Extra buttons column on add button click[image: Image i provide will give clear idea about problem]

Comment: Can you post more complete code please, showing page and button event handling?

Comment: Since you are adding the DGV columns manually you must set `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false`. Also: What is the `add button click` doing?

Comment: Take a look at this post. It contains all you need: [DataGridView with Button Control - Remove Row](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33549704/3110834)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to put your `List<T>` in a `DataTable`. Just set your list as `DataSource` of grid. Also using a `BindingList<T>` is a good option.

Comment: I am adding new row to grid by adding new employee to static list. that is where extra rows of buttons are created

Comment: I think here is the problem: In this line: dataGridView2.DataSource = null; //Button column still remains
Adding this line: dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false; //Extra empty columns.

Comment: It seems you didn't read the linked post.

Comment: Follow the Link to add dynamically Controls in a Cell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501740/how-to-add-contols-dynamically-in-datagridview-row-in-windows-form-application